# ReactJS and a backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am new to React. I created a simple login form and sign up form.
I am a little confused about using a backend. I've Googled it (lol) and I've seen a large variety of answers from using AWS to creating another project with NodeJS/Express.

For a beginner, what is the best approach? What confuses me is that I am handling all the routing in my React app. The tutorials that I've seen appear to handle routing in the NodeJS/Express portion.

Comment: ReactJS makes no assumptions about your backend.

Comment: Your question will get downvoted. SO is for answering specific programming questions, but your question is very broad and likely to get opinionated responses. I would suggest you get a boilerplate project from github, that uses reactjs and perhaps an express backend and then start from there.

Comment: Try first to search in google "create a simple REST API with Nodejs/Express" once you understand this concepts, you'll know what to change to make your form work.

Comment: @Appleshell -- _"ReactJS makes no assumptions about your backend."_ -- Nicely put. In fact, React makes no assumptions about whether there is a backend at all in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Chris mentioned your question is to broad to answer, but I'll try to propose some general directions which may help you to pursue building a back-end.

There is not really a best approach. I suggest you look into several courses and tutorials on what web technologies suits best for the type of application you want to build. Start first by selecting which framework would provide the most productive and scale-able workflow for you. This is depended on various factors of your envisioned application and your current skill-set. Then follow along tutorials and read documentation of each separate technology first to get a good understanding of each building block. When grasping how everything functions individually, looked in complete full stack tutorials to see how everything works together and how you connect your front-end to your back-end.

I chose for a Nodejs RESTfull API myself using the MERN stack (MongoDB, Express, Reactjs and Nodejs), but you can also look into python (django, flask) or PHP back-ends as well.

Some good Youtubers to get you started:
https://www.youtube.com/academind
https://www.youtube.com/traversymedia

They provide many up to date tutorials for different web-technologies so you can make an informed decision yourself of what you want to adapt to.

Keep in mind there is a lot to work with when you just getting started, but at some point things will become familiar after using it over and over again and it becomes less overwhelming.